# Distinguish TCP server from client within netstat output

Tags: linux, sockets, cmd

I use the command:
    netstat -tnp
the output like this:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       221.126.149.99:51973    ESTABLISHED 23879/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80        66.249.68.154:40883     ESTABLISHED 23899/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       66.249.68.81:41200      ESTABLISHED 23892/apache2
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80       66.249.67.121:59355     ESTABLISHED 23905/apache2
tcp        0   4465 0.0.0.0:80       110.75.175.27:48139     ESTABLISHED 23901/apache2
```

how can I distinguish TCP server from client within netstat output?

Comment: Your question doesn't really mean anything. Every line here refers to a connection *between* a client *and* a server, with the server's address being on the left in this case, as all the port numbers are the same.

Comment: This output makes no sense... how can a connection be `ESTABLISHED` on 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: you can only do something very very crude.

First, a process can be both a server and a client. So going by process is not going to work.

Second, once a TCP socket is established, it's symmetrical, there's no server or client. The fact that the client initiates the request emerges from the purpose of the established connection, rather than from the protocol rules. So just looking at the socket also won't work.

Theoretically, if an established socket remembered the "parent" socket, on which `accept(2)` was called, then netstat could have used that (no parent = client). But many, if not most/all kernels, don't remember that.

So the only thing you can do, is to look for connections in a `LISTEN` state, and all it tells you is that those are server connections, and their processes, are being used as servers.